# Is there a way to see if a value in a 2D array matches any value in another 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm building a battleship game in Javascript and React and I've been stuck on this issue for a while now even after much Googling and StackOverflowing.

Basically my board is a 2D array, with 10 arrays inside of one array. I'm trying to randomly place ships and I'm having difficulties checking if a ship intersects another ship.

Here's what I have for my ships:

```
placeShips = () => {
        // Logic to place boats randomly below

        // Checks required before placing a boat:
        // 1. Does the boat go off the board
        // 2. Does the boat overlap another boat
        // 3. If checks above pass then place boat


        let placedPosition = []
        let board = this.state.board.slice()
        let i
        for (i = 0; i < this.state.ships.length; i++) {
            // First randomly select coordinates for where the boat will start
            let xcoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
            let ycoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

            // Get positions in array where a boat will be
            let potentialBoat = []
            let newCoords

            let j
            for (j = 0; j < this.state.ships[i].getLength(); j++) {
                newCoords = [xcoord, ycoord + j]
                potentialBoat.push(newCoords)
```

The first for loop repeats for each ship left in my state to place and the second for loop takes a ship's length, gets the intended coordinate ([[0, 1], [0,2]] for a 2 length ship for example) and stores it in the potentialBoat array.

My idea is to use this potentialBoat array and see if there's any [xcoordinate, ycoordinate] that exists already in the placedPosition array and if so, to loop again for the current boat and get new coordinates until they don't intersect.

Is this possible? Or should I rethink my entire implementation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the inner loop, when in the process of creating a ship, consider creating a string representing the coordinates. Eg, for `newCoords` of `1, 3`, create a string `1_3`. To validate the location, check to see if that string exists in an array (or Set) of the locations of the *validated* ships. At the end of the inner loop, once all positions for the length of the ship have been validated, combine the possible-locations into the validated-locations array:

```
placeShips = () => {
  const placedPosition = [];
  const board = this.state.board.slice();
  const validatedPositionStrings = []; // <---- Create this array
  for (const ship of this.state.ships) {
    const thisShipLength = ship.getLength();
    tryShip:
    while (true) {
      const thisBoatPossiblePositionStrings = [];
      // Generate ship positions until valid
      const xcoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      const ycoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      const potentialBoat = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < thisShipLength; j++) {
        // Then check to see if the below position is already in it
        const thisCoordinateString = `${x}_${y}`; 
        if (validatedPositionStrings.includes(thisCoordinateString)) {
          // Invalid
          continue tryShip;
        }
        thisBoatPossiblePositionStrings.push(thisCoordinateString);

        // If this point is reached, then this particular coordinate is valid
        // do whatever you need to do:
        const newCoords = [xcoord, ycoord + j];
        potentialBoat.push(newCoords);
      }
      // All positions for ship are valid
      // do something with potentialBoat here?
      // push positions to placedPosition?
      validatedPositionStrings.push(...thisBoatPossiblePositionStrings);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

It could be made less computationally complex by using a Set instead of an array, but that probably doesn't matter unless there are a very large number of iterations.

It would also be possible to search your array of arrays to see if the position has already been placed, but that would require an unnecessary amount of code IMO.

If possible, you might consider changing your data structure around so that rather than an array of arrays, you have just a single object representing the coordinates, whose values indicate the ship at that position (and possibly other attributes needed for a particular point), eg:

```
{
  1_3: { ship: 'destroyer', 'attackedYet': 'false' }
  // ...
```

Such an object would probably be easier to look up and work through than an array of arrays of X-Y pairs.